# Merging objects from an array based on a property value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects in my JS app containing a date name, a date and some items:

```
const records = [
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '01/06/18', items: 12 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '01/06/18', items: 34 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '02/06/18', items: 13 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '02/06/18', items: 15 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '03/06/18', items: 55 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '04/06/18', items: 66 },
]
```

I would like to reduce this array so that objects with the same date will merged into one and the new items property will be the result of the sum of this property of the merged object. The result should be this:

```
const records = [
      { name: 'Carpat', date: '01/06/18', items: 46 },
      { name: 'Carpat', date: '02/06/18', items: 28 },
      { name: 'Carpat', date: '03/06/18', items: 55 },
      { name: 'Carpat', date: '04/06/18', items: 66 },
    ]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Re your comment on [the now-deleted repost of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723958/merging-objects-based-on-property): *'Just fixed it but, anyway..."* No, you didn't. I told you repeatedly how to, but you chose not to. We (Adriaan, Jonas W., and myself) did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a date hashtable and filter out dupes:

```
const hash = {};

const result = records.filter(el => {
  if(hash[el.date]) {
    hash[el.date].items += el.items;
    return false;
  } else {
    hash[el.date] = el;
    return true;
  }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const records = [
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '01/06/18', items: 12 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '01/06/18', items: 34 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '02/06/18', items: 13 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '02/06/18', items: 15 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '03/06/18', items: 55 },
  { name: 'Carpat', date: '04/06/18', items: 66 },
];

const hash = {};

const result = records.filter(el => {
  if(hash[el.date]) {
    hash[el.date].items += el.items;
    return false;
  } else {
    hash[el.date] = el;
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works...